# Does storm needs to implement ack and fail method or not

Tags: tuples, apache-storm

I am confuse by `ack()` and `fail()` methods in Storm.
Do I need to implement them when I send id with a tuple or are they already implemented in Storm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required in a strong sense. However, if you implement your own reliable Spout, you need to implement both:

First, you need to store all tuples (and its IDs) that get emitted in `nextTuple()` **reliably** such that you can replay them on failure! This is the most difficult part. Storing them in-memory is not save, as the spout could fail itself. Furthermore, the spout might get restarted on a different machine. Thus, you need to make sure that the storage is accessible in the whole cluster.

`ack()` will be called each time a tuple (and all its "child" tuples -- remember anchoring) got acked. The parameter will be the message ID that was assigned to the tuple originally. Thus, you can discard this tuple from your **reliable** storage.

`fail()` will be called each time a tuple (or one of its "child" tuples) times out or a bolt explicitly calls `collector.fail(...)`. Again, the parameter will be the message ID that was assigned to the tuple originally. For this case, you should replay the tuple, by emitting it to the same collector that you use in `nextTuple()`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, so if I used the following implementation

public void ack(Object msgId) {System.out.println("OK:"+msgId); }

public void fail(Object msgId) {System.out.println("FAIL:"+msgId); }

 UUID msgID = UUID.randomUUID();
     
this._collector.emit(new Values(line),msgID);

does that enough for reliability ?

Comment: No. In fail(), you do not replay, ie, emit, the tuple again. Btw: where do you consume your data from?

Comment: I got it
Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Matthias, can I emit a tuple in fail() method? because spout reads tuples from csv file. I have used hashmap to store tuples.

Comment: Yes, you can. But be aware that your solution with buffering tuples in `HashMap` is not reliable of spout fails!

Comment: Hi Matthias, if I have a spout emits to one bolt, do I need use fieldGrouping on id ?      because I couldn't understand fieldGrouping  is working just with more than one bolt or with one bolt that has several tasks as well ?.


Thanks

Comment: Yes. If you have an operation that requires partitioned data, you need to use fieldsGrouping if you have more than one task (even if you have only a single executor). FieldsGrouping partitions the data always on the number of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.